# How to setup a Docker Nginx reverse proxy when the app is running in a server

Tags: nginx

I have a application in a docker image working in a server of my company. To access the application, users need to do this

http://192.168.225.54:8080/

I want to create a reverse proxy. I am trying this with nginx which is also in a container.

Following [this tutorial][1] I have cp  default.conf from the docker

```
docker cp nginx-base:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf ~/Desktop/default.conf
```

I have added this

```
  location /spliceai-lookup {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.225.54:8080/;
  }
```

and I have copied the file back to the container

```
docker cp ~/Desktop/default.conf nginx-base:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

I have reload the container

```
sudo docker exec nginx-base nginx -t
sudo docker exec nginx-base nginx -s reload
```

And now following the tutorial I should be able to access my app if I type this `http://localhost/spliceai-lookup/`

However, this is not working and I think this is not working because in the tutorial he is working in the same computer where the app is running so the localhost works but in my case the app is running in a server and the localhost is not going to work because it is not local. Am I correct?

What I need to do to??

EDIT:

Another thing I wonder, do both container need to be connected to the same port. As explained in the tutorial first in 8080 but nginx is 80

```
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                       NAMES
192bfe6ee028   nginx:latest           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   22 minutes ago   Up 22 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp           nginx-base
d739cfdbcd8b   spliceailookup_local   "bash"                   2 hours ago      Up 2 hours      0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   gifted_thompson
```

In case someone ask. My application is Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8080
[1]: https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Docker-Nginx-reverse-proxy-setup-example